# Is there a way to move money between customers directly in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

Is it possible to move money between Stripe customers through ACH without having to use the merchant, myself, as an intermediary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To facilitate payments through Stripe between users of product, you'd need to have them create Connect accounts. You can read about the process of making payouts in [the stripe docs](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payouts). It is currently impossible to transfer money between Customers.

It may be worth going through [Stripe's list of prohibited businesses](https://stripe.com/us/prohibited-businesses) as "Money Transmitters" generally aren't allowed. Where here that is defined as transferring money without the sale of a good or service. If you want to know whether you'd run afoul of this, I recommend writing into [Stripe's support](https://support.stripe.com/email/login).